# Infinite Carousel Slide Offset on Mobile

Tags: jquery, infinite-carousel

I have a site that uses infinite carousel and on desktop the carousel shows 3 slides. On mobile it only shows 1 and that's perfect. However, it shows the 2nd slide in chronological order. Is there a way to change the offset so that it shows the first one and not the second on mobile?

I'm at a loss here and I can't figure out a way to make the actual first slide(according to post date) show up on mobile first.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add an if statement that checked the screen width via jQuery. When the screen got to a certain size I just changed the offset to accommodate the 1 slide at a time.